# Why can I reverse a hash (sha512 f.ex.) with online tools?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I keep reading that hashing is irreversible, but if I create a SHA512 for instance on http://www.sha1-online.com/, then try and reverse it with a different tool (https://md5hashing.net/hash/sha512 f.ex.), I actually get the correct output - from the looks of it, the hash has been reversed.

Or has it - what am I getting wrong?

Comment: SHA hashes are deterministic, which makes it so that you can build a lookup table, that's all there is to it. I just fed a hash of your name into that tool and it says *"Reverse decryption is failed."* (sic)

Comment: So in essence, those tools just show a random entry from a lookup table, at the risk of showing the wrong one?

Comment: Define "wrong". They show an input that matches the hash. There's no way to reconstitute the input that was originally used to create the hash. Due to the nature of hashing, hashing the bible might yield the same result as hashing "Hello world".

Comment: By "wrong" I mean another input that matches the same hash - but I think  I get it now: they've probably just made a huge table with many possible input/hash combinations and the reversal is just the lookup. Thanks @RobbyCornelissen !

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table